# Find last day of a month and year VisualBasic

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I'm trying to get the last day of a Month and Year, but I can't find where is my error on my code...

I have this function

```
  Private Function Ultim_dia(mes As String) As String
    Dim ultim As String
    ultim = 1
    Select Case (mes)
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
            ultim = "31"

        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
            ultim = "30"

        Case 2
            If ((mes) Mod 4) = 0 Then
                ultim = "29"

            Else
                ultim = "28"

            End If
    End Select
    Return ultim
End Function
```

And on my OnclickButton I have this code

```
 Dim ultim As String
    ultim = tbMes.Text


    Ultim_dia(ultim)
    Select Case (ultim)
        Case "29"
            Me.lb_UltimoDia.Text = "29"
        Case "28"
            Me.lb_UltimoDia.Text = "28"
        Case "30"
            Me.lb_UltimoDia.Text = "30"
        Case "31"
            Me.lb_UltimoDia.Text = "31"
    End Select
```

I don't know where i'm wrong, I'm seeing that I don't use my year anywhere... i don't know if this is the problem.

I wish you can help me, it is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button click will call the function that will return the no.of days in the year and month that are passed to the function.

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Dim ultim As String = noOfdays(1989, 8)
 End Sub
 '<-- function
 Public Function noOfdays(ByVal year As Integer, ByVal month As Integer) As String
   Try
        noOfdays = Date.DaysInMonth(year, month)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
 End Function
```

Comment: What about If I want to add a Try Catch of the fuction, I mean, I have all of those Integers on TextBox and I want to know If the used puts a number <1 or >12

Comment: Oh, thank you so much... Now I'm wondering if I can change the MsgButton caption... Can I?

Answer (score 4):

To get the number of days in the month use the [DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth(v=vs.110).aspx) built in function.

```
Dim currentDate As Date = Date.Now
Dim lastDayOfMo = Date.DaysInMonth(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month)
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a month and year (month=10 and year='2014')

Create a new date of the first day of the next month

```
Dim q as new date("1", month+1, "2014")
```

Then do a dateadd of negative one date

```
dim a as new date = dateadd("d",-1,q)
```

That should give you the last date of the original month.

Answer (score 1):

Tested in VBA, presumably works in VB.NET as well:

```
Function LastDayOfMonth(theMonth As Long, theYear As Long) As Date
    LastDayOfMonth = DateSerial(theYear, theMonth + 1, 0)
End Function
```

For example, to get the last day of October 2014:

```
Dim d As Date
d = LastDayOfMonth(10, 2014) ' returns 31 Oct 2014
```

Comment: What does VBA have to do with the question? ;)

Comment: The [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26643494/1) was tagged VBA. Besides, the answer applies to VB.NET as well.

Comment: Ok, I see.. sorry I just found this to be out of context before I've seen revision. well ... ++